# System of differential equations, phase portraits and stability of fixed points

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the system of differential equations:

$$x'=-x-y+4$$
$$y'=3-xy$$

a. Find the fixed points.

$x'=-x-y+4$

$x+y=4$

$x+3/x=4$

x=3,x=1

$y'=3-xy$

$y=3/x$

fixed points: (1,3), (3,1)

b. Determine the type of the linearized system at each fixed point.

calculating the Jacobian:

\begin{array}{cc}
   -1 & -1 \\
   -y & -x \\
  \end{array}

for the fixed point (1,3):
 \begin{array}{cc}
   -1 & -1 \\
   -3 & -1 \\
  \end{array}

calculating eigenvalues:

$λ_1=-1-\sqrt 3$ (could be positive or negative)
$λ_2=\sqrt 3-1$ (negative)

So it is unstable (I think, because if we use the negative root of 3, then the first eigenvalue is positive, is this correct?

for the fixed point (3,1):
 \begin{array}{cc}
   -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -3 \\
  \end{array}

calculating eigenvalues:

$λ_1=-2-\sqrt 2$ (negative)
$λ_2=\sqrt 2-2$ (negative)

So it is stable

C. Determine the nullclines and the signs of $x'$ and $y'$ on the nullclines and in the various regions determined by them.  (I'm not sure I am calculating the signs of $x'$ and $y'$ correctly)

y-nullcine: $y'=3/x$ 
x-nullcine: $y=4-x$

R1

$x'<00$
$y'>0$

R2

$x'<0$
$y'>0$

R3

$x'>0$
$y'<0$

R4

$x'<00$
$y'<0$

R5

$x'<0$
$y'<0$

R6

$x'0$
$y'<0$

[image]

d. Draw the phase plane portrait[image]

Comment: So is the general method to look at the phase portrait to determine the positive and negative roots, or the opposite, do I need to determine the roots to draw the phase portrait?

Comment: I get everything about the critical points and nullclines, but I guess the problem is I am still a little confused about how to draw the direction fields or how I can determine the direction lines if I don't have the phase portrait to work backwards from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phase portrait:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Fixed points:

- At $(3,1)$, Jacobian matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\-1&-3\end{pmatrix}$, trace $-4$ (negative), determinant $+2$ (positive), discriminant $(-4)^2-4\cdot(+2)=8$ (positive), hence two real negative eigenvalues: the point $(3,1)$ is a *stable node*
- At $(1,3)$, Jacobian matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\-3&+1\end{pmatrix}$, trace $0$, determinant $-4$ (negative), hence two real eigenvalues of opposite signs: the point $(1,3)$ is a *saddle point*

...As explained there:

$\qquad$[image]